# ASP.NET MVC parser error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc application on IIS 6.0 webserver. The problem is: i get a parser error. I tried with the default sample asp.net mvc project but i get the same error:

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'SampleApp._Default'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleApp._Default" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <%-- Please do not delete this file. It is used to ensure that ASP.NET MVC is activated by IIS when a user makes a "/" request to the server. --%>

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082
```

I dont have access to the iis because it is running on hosting srv. I set the routing in the global.asax.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The virtual dir. was not configured correctly.

Comment: This answer could use some elaboration. What exactly wasn't configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To make ASP.NET MVC work in IIS, you need to change a couple of things. There are two or three methods which are described [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/). You might want to go for the second option, as you said you have no access to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Is ASP.Net MVC installed on the server?

If not, not is all lost. You can right click on the ASP.NET MVC references and set "Copy Local" to true.

Comment: MVC's dlls arent in the GAC but i uploaded to to bin dir.